# What the "core.???" files in Couchbase do?

Tags: couchbase, membase

I'm using the Membase mode of Couchbase(1.8) now.
The "core.???" files in couchbase's data directory eat up all the space of the disk and then Couchbase crashed.

I recovered the couchebase service after I delete all of them.

What do these files do and how can I prevent Couchbase crashing from this problem?

Comment: Core dump files? That would imply a couchbase component is crashing a lot .... (before it runs out of disk space). You might be able to analyze with: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-cmdline-cbanalyze-core.html